# Application data in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Say I have some objects that need to be created only once in the application yet accessed from within multiple requests. The objects are immutable. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Store them in the session.
If you don't want to lose them after a server's restart, then use a database (SQLite, which is a single file, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You want to persist your objects. Normally you'd do it with some ORM like Active Record or Datamapper. Depending on what is available to you. If you want something dead simple without migrations and you have access to a MongoDB use mongomapper.

Answer (score 0):

If that object is used only for some time, then it is discarded (and if needed again, then recreated), use some caching mechanism, like memcached or redis.

If setting up such services is heavy and you want to avoid it, and - say - you are using Debian/Ubuntu then save your objects into files (with Marshal-ing) in the /shm device which is practically memory.

If the structure of the data is complex, then go with SQLite as suggested above.